# GA google / organic traffic from GA API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Hello there I am trying to get Google/ organic traffic for a particular month using GA API.
Using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETg20.png)

Where I have tried dimensions  as ['month', 'year' ] and ['sourceMedium'] using the metrics as  ['organicSearches'] but I am getting the values that are not matching which are shown on  the dashboard.

[image: Trying to access this value]

Any suggestions what dimension should I use to get this ??

Comment: Have you tried using the [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)?

Comment: @Blexy yes tried using that giving me similar result. Could you please  help me in making the query? Coz I have tried ga:sourceMedium, ga:organicSearches and still getting incorrect Output

Comment: just to supplement Blexy's answer, organic searches (metric) represents "the number of organic searches that happened within a session".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you're looking for visits, so you'll have to include that as a metric. You get `google / organic` by providing a filter for `ga:sourceMedium`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Ton @Blexy. I have wasted my whole day in figuring out the exact result and was unable to get that.